# Component Initialization Infinite Loop - Angular 2 JSPM

Tags: javascript, angular, jspm

Here is the full error.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Injector._instantiate (http://localhost:8000/build.js:36366:63)
at Injector._instantiateProvider (http://localhost:8000/build.js:36244:23)
at Injector._new (http://localhost:8000/build.js:36234:21)
at InjectorInlineStrategy.instantiateProvider (http://localhost:8000/build.js:35998:30)
at ElementDirectiveInlineStrategy.init (http://localhost:8000/build.js:35106:20)
at new AppElement (http://localhost:8000/build.js:34800:24)
at viewFactory_constructor0 (viewFactory_constructor:74:26)
at viewFactory_constructor0 (viewFactory_constructor:76:1)
at viewFactory_constructor0 (viewFactory_constructor:76:1)
at viewFactory_constructor0 (viewFactory_constructor:76:1) <app id="NG2_UPGRADE_0_app_c0">
```

Here is my source file.

```
import 'reflect-metadata'

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'

console.log('Files have started being compiled and infinite loop has begun');

var TodoCmpTest = 
Component({
  selector: 'todo-cmp'
})
.View({
  template: `<h1>TodoCmpTest</h1>`
})
.Class({
  constructor: function(){
    console.log('hello');
  }
});


var AppComponent = 
Component({
  selector: 'app',
})
.View({
  template: `
  <div>
  <h1> Hello World </h1>
  <todo-cmp></todo-cmp>
  </div>
  `,
  directives: [TodoCmpTest]
// directives: []
})
.Class({
  constructor: function () {}
});  

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Its reinstatiating TodoCmpTest over and over again.

If you swap these two lines it works, but doesn't load TodoCmpTest.

`directives: [TodoCmpTest]
// directives: []`

## You can reproduce this error by doing the following...

`1. git clone https://github.com/danielrasmuson/Angular2HelloWorld-StackOverflow
2. use node v5.4.0
3. jspm install
4. npm install
5. npm start`

Comment: I had a somewhat similar issue, try using one file for each component and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Langley. Yes I had it in multiple files, but I merged the files for the example. :/

Comment: What ng2 are you using? Are you using minified or non minified bundles?

Comment: In the above I'm using 'npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.1' and I'm loading it via the above jspm import.

Comment: I tried reproducing your issue but when I try to follow your steps, npm throws an error: ` @ start: `./node_modules/live-server/live-server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1` I noticed your index file is pointing to the wrong angular version, not the beta though.

Comment: Thanks @Langley for checking this out. an alternative to `npm start` would be `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and goto `localhost:8000` in your browser. My index.html loads angular1 through a script tag and angular2 is loaded through jspm via the import statements you see in `lib/main.js` (You can confirm this by watching the network tab).

Comment: have you tried the pointers in this example? http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-components-angular-2-typescript-es5/

Comment: It sounds similar (but not equal) to this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6366). A lot of issues were introduced with beta 1 (with minification). Have you tried with beta 0 or lower and with non minified bundles? (I don't know how JSPM works)

Answer (score 3):

It seems it's an angular 2 problem in the beta 1,
I tried your repo with angular 2 beta 0 and it worked fine, no loop.
I suggest you stick with beta 0, until they fix it.
I don't know jspm, so here is what i did to test it: (not everything here might be needed but just editing package.json -> removing -> and reinstalling kept installing me the angular beta 1 version)

edited the package.json angular2 dependency to:

```
"jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "angular2": "npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.0",
      "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@^0.1.3"
    },
```

then i run

```
rm -rf jspm_packages/npm/angular2@2.0.0-beta.1
jspm install npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.0  
npm start
```

Comment: Same problem with beta6/7, any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I faced with same issue. I used webpack and babel + es2015 preset to bundle my code. I realized that if in bundle I have next code all work well:

```
Component({
    ...
    directives: [SuperComponent]
}).Class({
    constructor: function() {}
});
```

but if I have next I got inifinity loop:

```
Component({
    ...
    //Important: reproduces only with not empty directives that used in template
    directives: [SuperComponent] 
}).Class({
    constructor: function costructor() {}
});
```

I didn't investigate why it happens, but I believe its some internal angular2 issue. As workaround I created es2015 preset without function-name plugin that causes this transformation: 
https://github.com/DontRelaX/babel-preset-es2015-without-function-name

Hope it will save you hour or two. Going to create issue in angular2 repo.

Answer (score 0):

If this is being cause by a loop not stopping then using `break;` on the line below `directives: [TodoCmpTest]` will stop this loop.

Not sure if this will work but give it a try, it might.